# Swift array accessors 5 times slower than native arrays - which are the recommended ones?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, metal

I'm doing loops on big arrays (images) and through Instruments I found out that the major bottleneck was `Array.subscript.nativePinningMutableAddressor`, so I made this unit tests to compare,

```
// average: 0.461 seconds (iPhone6 iOS 10.2) ~5.8 times slower than native arrays
func testArrayPerformance() {
    self.measure {
        var array = [Float](repeating: 1, count: 2048 * 2048)
        for i in 0..<array.count {
            array[(i+1)%array.count] = Float(i)
        }
    }
}

// average: 0.079 seconds
func testNativeArrayPerformance() {
    self.measure {
        let count = 2048 * 2048
        let array = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>.allocate(capacity: count)
        for i in 0..<count {
            array[(i+1)%count] = Float(i)
        }
        array.deallocate(capacity: count)
    }
}
```

As you can see, the native array is much faster. Is there any other way to access the array faster? "Unsafe" doesn't sound "safe", but what would you guys do in this situation? Is there any other type of array that wraps a native one?

For a more complex example, you can see follow the comments in this article: [Rendering Text in Metal with Signed-Distance Fields](http://metalbyexample.com/rendering-text-in-metal-with-signed-distance-fields/)
I re-implemented that example in Swift, and the original implementation took 52 seconds to start up, https://github.com/endavid/VidEngine/tree/textprimitive-fail

After switching to native arrays, I went down to 10 seconds, https://github.com/endavid/VidEngine/tree/fontatlas-array-optimization

Tested on Xcode 8.3.3.

Edit1:
The timings for this test are in Debug configuration, but the timings for the Signed Distance Fields example are in Release configuration. Thanks for the micro-optimizations (count, initialization) for the unit tests in the comments, but in the real world example those are negligible and the memory buffer solution is still 5 times faster on iOS.

Edit2:
Here are the timings (Instruments session on iPhone6) of the most expensive functions in the Signed Distance Fields example,

using Swift arrays,
[image: Using Swift arrays]

using memory buffers,
[image: Using memory buffers]

Edit3: apart from performance issues, I had severe memory problems using Swift arrays. `NSKeyedArchiver` would run out of memory and crash the app. I had to use the byte buffer instead, and store it in a `NSData`. Ref. commit: https://github.com/endavid/VidEngine/commit/6c1822523a2b18759f294def3188755eaaf98b41

So I guess the answer to my question is: for big arrays of numeric data (e.g. images), better use memory buffers.

Comment: Did you do your timings using a debug or release build?

Comment: You do realize that a swift array is a native array right? What you're using is raw pointers AKA a bridge to the akin of a C like array. It's not a 'native' array. It's a memory buffer. This will always be faster as you're accessing and managing memory rather having a bridged object to do so. Mind you, it 100% matters what debug flags you have set when it comes to Swift when benchmarking speed.

Comment: @endavid Another difference: `[Float](repeating: 1, count: 2048 * 2048)` does a full pass through the array to set all the elements to `1`. Your pointer code doesn't do an equivalent operation

Comment: Also, the `count` is a constant in a second example, and a repeatedly-accessed property in the first. In unoptimized builds, this will make a difference

Comment: Fastest solution of them all: `let array = [count - 1] + stride(from: 0, to: count, by: +1)`

Comment: I wonder why he set `repeating` to 1. Maybe the OP believes it's the number of times the operation is repeated (i.e. "do this just once") and not the initial value for the array elements? (Just like how it works with `calloc()`.)

Answer (score 6):

Simply caching the `count` improved the speed from 0.2s to 0.14s, which is twice the time it takes the pointer-based code. This is entirely expected, given that the array based code does a preinitialization of all elements to `1`.

Baseline:

[image]

After caching the `count`:

[image]

Comment: Great tests. Could you try them again, moving the array creation into a setup function to remove the impact on the timing?

Comment: @GaryMakin I have this project on another computer. I'll give it a shot when I get back to it

Answer (score 2):

I decided to test the uninitialized Array performance on my 2014 Macbook Pro :

```
// average: 0.315 seconds (macOS Sierra 10.12.5)
func testInitializedArrayPerformance() {
    self.measure {
        var array = [Float](repeating: 1, count: 2048 * 2048)
        for i in 0..<array.count {
            array[(i+1)%array.count] = Float(i)
        }
    }
}

// average: 0.043 seconds (macOS Sierra 10.12.5)
func testUninitializedArrayPerformance() {
    self.measure {
        var array : [Float] = []
        array.reserveCapacity(2048 * 2048)
        array.append(0)
        for i in 0..<(2048 * 2048) {
            array.append(Float(i))
        }
        array[0] = Float(2048 * 2048-1)
    }
}

// average: 0.077 seconds (macOS Sierra 10.12.5)
func testNativeArrayPerformance() {
    self.measure {
        let count = 2048 * 2048
        let array = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>.allocate(capacity: count)
        for i in 0..<count {
            array[(i+1)%count] = Float(i)
        }
        array.deallocate(capacity: count)
    }
}
```

This confirms that the array initialization is causing a big performance hit.

Comment: Thanks for checking. If you check the complex example I linked to, Signed Distance Fields, I do have a loop for the initialization of the memory buffer, since in both cases the arrays need to be initialized. The initialization time in that case is negligible, but the memory buffer version is still 5 times faster.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Alexander, `UnsafeMutablePointer` is not a *native array*, it's just a pointer operation.

Testing on iPhone 7+/iOS 10.3.2, in equivalent condition (both initialized) with Release build:

```
//0.030,0.027,0.017,0.027,0.024 -> avg 0.025
func testArrayPerformance2() {
    self.measure {
        let count = 2048 * 2048
        var array = [Float](repeating: 1, count: count)
        for i in 0..<count {
            array[(i+1)%count] = Float(i)
        }
    }
}

//0.021,0.022,0.011,0.021,0.021 -> avg 0.0192
func testPointerOpPerformance2() {
    self.measure {
        let count = 2048 * 2048
        let array = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>.allocate(capacity: count)
        array.initialize(to: 1, count: count)
        for i in 0..<count {
            array[(i+1)%count] = Float(i)
        }
        array.deinitialize(count: count)
        array.deallocate(capacity: count)
    }
}
```

Not a big difference. Less than 2 times. (About 1.3 times.)

Generally, Swift optimizer for Arrays work well for:

- Block-local variables
- Private properties

Whole Module Optimization would affect, but I have not tested.

If your *more complex example* takes 5 times to start up, it may be written in a hard-to-optimize manner. (Please pick up the core parts affecting the performance and include it in your question.)

Comment: The "pointer operation" would be accessing that memory buffer with the square bracket operator, but not the buffer itself. The same way you overuse words to make it easier to understand, I thought that it would be easier to call an "array" something that looks and behaves as an array. In the C world everything would be pointers, but addressing them with square brackets usually means you can call it a vector or an array. Sorry for the confusion. I've added some timings of the other example. I don't see any bottleneck other than `nativePinningMutableAddressor`.

Comment: You can call it _native array_ in the C world. But we are talking about Swift. And if `nativePinningMutableAddressor` is being the cause of your app's performance issue, your app is coded in a manner that Swift optimizer cannot eliminate it.